# How to find the element using selenium for below code?

Tags: selenium

`"input type="button" onclick="Save(this)" value="Save"`

I am trying to find this element using selenium webdriver with c# .

How to find the element?

Answer (score 1):

Xpath:

```
//input[@type='button']
//input[@value='Save']
```

assuming input is unique.

Css Selector:

```
input[type='button']
input[value='Save']
```

assumine input is unique.

Check it out here. [selenium cheat sheet link](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=selenium%20cheat%20sheet&espv=2&biw=1536&bih=764&tbm=isch&imgil=j5ipUh0TO-cBPM%253A%253B61vQeyHuFk4NgM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.simple-talk.com%25252Fdotnet%25252Fnet-framework%25252Fxpath-css-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=j5ipUh0TO-cBPM%253A%252C61vQeyHuFk4NgM%252C_&usg=__O6YFx1ES-PUIH0X5RZoq49KWeCo%3D&dpr=1.25&ved=0ahUKEwj_i9DnvM_OAhWCrJQKHU3qBbEQyjcILA&ei=RQe4V7_VHYLZ0gTN1JeICw#imgrc=j5ipUh0TO-cBPM%3A)